# Java Slic2D erorr

Tags: java, lwjgl

When I add this code:

```
    otionHover = false;
    if(optionRect.contains(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY())) {
        otionHover = true;
        if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
            System.out.println("The button was pressed!");
        }
    }
```

I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   lt.CobaltPlanet.nelixus.state.GameMenu.init(GameMenu.java:26)     at
>   lt.CobaltPlanet.nelixus.Main.initStatesList(Main.java:55)     at
>   org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:164)
>     at
>   org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:393)
>     at
>   org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
>     at lt.CobaltPlanet.nelixus.Main.main(Main.java:74)

Answer (score 0):

`optionRect` is null. Make sure to assign something to it, probably a Rectangle.

```
optionRect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
```

Is what you need. Just add proper values and it should work.

Comment: maybe can i ask how to do it?

Comment: i have:
 optionRect = new Rectangle(205, 200, option.getWidth(), option.getHeight());

Comment: no i geting this erorr any help?

Comment: i don't know how to fix it pleas help!